# Is it possible to re-ingest (sink connector) data into the db if some messages got missed entering

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

Currently I setup 2 separate connectors running the JDBC Sink Connector to ingest topics produced from the producer to be read into the database. Sometimes, I see errors in the logs, which cause messages produced fails to get stored into the database.
The errors I constantly see is

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id:11
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject 'topic-io..models.avro.Topic' not found; error code404
```

Which is true because TopicRecordName is not supposed to be directed toward this topic but another topic that I directed to, it is just supposed to be directed toward `models.avro.Topic`

I was wondering if this happens constantly, is there a way to re-ingest those produced records/messages into the database after the messages got produced. For example, if messages got produced during 12am-1am, and some kind of errors showed up in the logs and failed to consume those messages during that timeframe, the configurations or offset can restore it by re-ingesting it to the database. The error is due to the schema registry link failed to read/ link to the correct schema link. It failed because it read the incorrect worker file, since one of my worker file have a `value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy` while the other connector does not read that subjectName.

Currently, I set the `consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest` to start reading message.
Is there a way to get back those data like into a file and I can restore those data because I am deploying to production and there must be data consumed into the database at all times without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mess with the consumer group offsets, which would eventually cause correctly processed data to get consumed again and duplicated, you could use the dead letter queue configurations to send error records to a new topic, which you'd need to monitor and consume before the topic retention completely drops the events

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/

> one of my worker file have a [different config]

This is why configuration management software is important. Don't modify one server in a distributed system without a process that updates them all. Ansible/Terraform are most common if you're not running the connectors in Kubernetes

Comment: does using dead letter queue restore the data, what do you mean send error records to a new topic. I just want to restore those lost messages into a backup and re-ingest it maually like a snapshot. Should I set it to latest instead of earliest then

Comment: No, it doesn't restore anything, it moves all error causing records to a brand new topic such that the whole, original consumer group doesn't stop and crash. You therefore would need multiple connectors to read from both topics. Offset reset value has nothing to do with that

Comment: I kind of don't quite follow you. When you say it moves all errors to a new topic and multiple topics to read from both topic? Does that mean we have topic1 moves to topic2 as a new topic and topic2 will also generate new records based off of topic1. And topic1 and topic2 will have the same records? Can you make it simpler

Comment: I am just trying to see is there any possibility to re-ingest lost records because this is in production. I want to know is there a way to have like a snapshot and I re-put it back into the database myself/manually through a file

Comment: No, the dead letter queue will contain all records that failed from the first consumer connector. You shouldn't use the same connector to read from both topics because they're likely to fail again, and you'd end up with some infinite consumer loop... Like I said already, yes, it's possible to do what you want. Not with a snapshot, and not with a file, but a second topic... Did you read the linked blog?

Comment: yes I just re-read the blog and all the fields they mentioned as error.tolerance=all I initially already set. But my question is when I deploy the second connector and say that the dead queue topic is topicA where will I see the error message value, would it get restored to database if I don't set it in a file.txt. I am just confused on the part after setup where the records get recorded/spit out the record

Comment: On its own `errors.tolerance=all` skips all the bad messages

Comment: If you set `errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name`, then that's were the error causing records will go to... You then need to consume **that** topic **_as well_** (ideally with error tolerance set to none) to get all original topic data into the sink